# about sharedInstance SOMotionDetector and SOStepDetector objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm working on the following code, which has the steps of a person walking. but every time I step from one view to another the counter stops. I am working with SOMotionDetector.

NOTE: when printing to console the steps that continues to function even changing views.

```
#import "SOMotionDetector.h"
#import "SOStepDetector.h"

@interface ContarPasos ()<SOMotionDetectorDelegate>
{
    int stepCount;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *speedLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *stepCountLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *motionTypeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *isShakingLabel;

@end

@implementation ContarPasos

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

__strong ContarPasos *weakSelf = self;
[SOMotionDetector sharedInstance].motionTypeChangedBlock = ^(SOMotionType motionType) {
    NSString *type = @"";
    switch (motionType) {
        case MotionTypeNotMoving:
            type = @"No estas moviendote";
            break;
        case MotionTypeWalking:
            type = @"Caminando";
            break;
        case MotionTypeRunning:
            type = @"Corriendo";
            break;
        case MotionTypeAutomotive:
            type = @"Automotive";
            break;
    }
    weakSelf.motionTypeLabel.text = type;
};

[SOMotionDetector sharedInstance].locationChangedBlock = ^(CLLocation *location) {
    weakSelf.speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f km/h",        [SOMotionDetector sharedInstance].currentSpeed * 3.6f];
};

[SOMotionDetector sharedInstance].accelerationChangedBlock = ^(CMAcceleration acceleration) {
    BOOL isShaking = [SOMotionDetector sharedInstance].isShaking;
    weakSelf.isShakingLabel.text = isShaking ? @"Corriendo":@"No corriendo";
};

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
    [SOMotionDetector sharedInstance].useM7IfAvailable = YES; //Use M7 chip if available, otherwise use lib's algorithm
}

[[SOMotionDetector sharedInstance] startDetection];
[[SOStepDetector sharedInstance] startDetectionWithUpdateBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
        return;
    }
    stepCount++;
    weakSelf.stepCountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pasos: %d", stepCount];  
    NSLog(@"always printed on console but not in the view: %d", stepCount);

    }];   
}
```